How to change python version
I have Python 3.11, and I want 3.8. I downloaded 3.8, and removed 3.11 from path. My command prompt says:
C:\Users\forha>python --version
Python 3.8.0

In VScode, my terminal says
C:\Users\forha\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\F1car-wAI>python --version
Python 3.11.0

I've tried changing the python interpreter, but it still always says "Python 3.11.0" when I run
python --version

Thanks for the help!

Close the VSCode terminal and close and reopen VSCode. The terminal usually needs to be restarted after changing your PATH.
